# Can you add multiple authentication provider for an API via Azure Api gateway?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I was wondering if it's possible to add more then one authentication provider to protect an API endpoint via Azure API gateway.

From the portal, it doesn't seem like it is possible since it only allows you to select one?  Wonder if there is a workaround?

For example, I want a user to be able to sign in to google and as well as facebook via openIDConnect.  Based on successful validate-jwt in the policy of the API be able to hit the actual endpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only one provider can be associated with an API at the moment. But this association does not affect runtime request processing in any way, it's purely for documentation and test console purposed. So if those are not important to you it should not be a big deal.